# Pass the EditText.getText from FirstFragment to SecondFragment when the User swipes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe

what i'm trying to do:
in FirstFragment the user can type in his weight.
in SecondFragment the weight should be shown in a TextView
the Value should be passed on swipe of the user.

i tried arround 3 how-to's and read a lot about fragments but i still couldn't find a suitable solution. As i'm kind of new to fragments it could also be that i made a uncommon way to generate fragments and it therefore doesn't work but i couldn't figure it out yet.

As you can se unerneath actually there is an error in the code because i tried to get access to the method of FirstFragment through the MainActivity

To simplyfy, i don't poste the whole code of the two fragment xlm's.
first_frag.xml have a EditText (id: getWeight) Box where you only can enter numbers up to 3 digits
second_frag.xml has a TextView (id: txtAlcLvl)

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;
    String TabFragmentB;



    public void setTabFragmentB(String t){
        TabFragmentB = t;
    }

    public String getTabFragmentB(){
        return TabFragmentB;
    }

    public Calculator getCalc(){
        return this.calc;
    }

    public void getWeight(){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FirstFragment fragment = (FirstFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.i_dont_know_the_id);
        //failure because trying to get access to Method of FirstFragment
        fragment.getWeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);


        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(final int i, final float v, final int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(final int i) {
                YourFragmentInterface fragment = (YourFragmentInterface) pagerAdapter.instantiateItem(pager, i);
                if (fragment != null) {
                    fragment.fragmentBecameVisible();
                }
            }



            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int i) {
            }
        });

    }


    public interface YourFragmentInterface {
        void fragmentBecameVisible();
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position) {

                case 1: return new SecondFragment(); //SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");

                case 0: return new FirstFragment();

                default: return new FirstFragment(); //FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Default");
            }
        }




        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

FirstFragment.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements MainActivity.YourFragmentInterface {

    Button btnBeer;
    Button btnBeerSmall;
    Button btnWine;
    Button btnLiq;
    Button btnSch;
    Button btnWater;
    Button btnMale;
    Button btnFemale;
    Calculator calc;
    EditText getWeight;

    public String getWeight(){
        return getWeight.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void fragmentBecameVisible() {



        // You can do your animation here because we are visible! (make sure onViewCreated has been called too and the Layout has been laid. Source for another question but you get the idea.
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);
        calc = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCalc();

        btnBeer = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnBeer);
        btnBeerSmall = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnBeerSmall);
        btnWine = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnWine);
        btnLiq = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnLiq);
        btnSch = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSch);
        btnWater = (Button) v.findViewById((R.id.btnWater));
        btnMale = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnMale);
        btnFemale = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnFemale);
        getWeight = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.getWeight);

        btnBeer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calc.addConsumption(0);
            }
        });

        btnBeerSmall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calc.addConsumption(1);
            }
        });

        btnWine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calc.addConsumption(2);
            }
        });

        btnLiq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calc.addConsumption(3);
            }
        });

        btnSch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calc.addConsumption(4);
            }
        });

        btnWater.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calc.addConsumption(5);
            }
        });

        btnMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnMale.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.male_false);
                btnFemale.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.female);
            }
        });

        btnFemale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnFemale.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.female_false);
                btnMale.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.male);
            }
        });


        return v;

    }

    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

        FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);


        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }
}
```

SecondFragment.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements MainActivity.YourFragmentInterface {


    TextView txtAlcLvl;
    TextView txtTimeToZero;
    TextView txtPeak;
    ImageButton btnReset;
    Calculator calc;
    String weight;



    @Override
    public void fragmentBecameVisible() {
        calc.person.setSex(false);
        calc.person.setWeight(80);
        txtAlcLvl.setText(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getWeight());
        //txtAlcLvl.setText(String.format("%.2f", calc.getCurrentLevel()) + "‰");

        // You can do your animation here because we are visible! (make sure onViewCreated has been called too and the Layout has been laid. Source for another question but you get the idea.
    }

    public void setSex(){

    }

    public void setWeight(){
        try{

        }   catch(NumberFormatException e){

        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag, container, false);
        calc = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCalc();
        String myTag = getTag();
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setTabFragmentB(myTag);

        txtAlcLvl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtAlcLvl);
        txtTimeToZero = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeToZero);
        txtPeak = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtPeak);
        btnReset = (ImageButton) v.findViewById((R.id.btnReset));

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calc.resetConsumption();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public void updateText(String t){
        txtAlcLvl.setText(t);
    }

    public static SecondFragment newInstance(String text) {

        SecondFragment f = new SecondFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it the over way round.
Instead of trying to get the weight in activity from your fragment, try to set the weight on the activity from the fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  ...
  private float weight;

  public void setWeight(float weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
  }

  public float getWeight() {
    return this.weight();
  }
```

Then in your FirstFragment:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).setWeight(...);
```

And finally in your SecondFragment:

```
float weight = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getWeight();
```

Comment: This would be the easiest way.  Using persistent storage to pass an int is overkill.

Comment: First thank you for your suggestion, i now implemented this to my app. But there is one thing i still don't get. i need to pass the EditText.getText to the SecondFragment when the user swipe the Screen because bevore, he couldn't input anything to this EditText. How can i get this done?

Comment: Well the idea between my answer was that you would not pass the EditText.getText to the SecondFragment, but the SecondFragment would retrieve it. This could be done in the onStart method of the fragment by means of calling the getWeight method in the activity...

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to "pass" the value like you would normally expect when an activity is invoking a new fragment.

Instead, consider using some persistent storage to store the value, such as SharedPreferences or a Sqlite database.  Each fragment can read and write values out of there as needed.